# JQ Grid Issue using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, jqgrid-asp.net

When I am taken Empty project sample from Visual Studio then JQ Grid working perfectly in VS 2013. When I Select 'Asp.net Web Form Site' then JQ Grid is not working. Because some folder will come default like Account, web config and so on, into ASP.NET Web Form Site. I also install new version of JG Grid version: "4.5.2" and below added links into the head.

```
<link href="jqGrid/css/jqGrid.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="jqGrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
```

Below is my code working into Visual Studio 2010:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>

<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="JQGridReq/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQGridReq/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JQGridReq/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default5.aspx/GetDataFromDB") %>',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },

        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        loadonce: true,
        //toolbar: [true, "top"],
        colNames: ['Emp_ID', 'Name', 'Designation', 'City', 'State', 'Country'],
        colModel: [
                   { name: 'Emp_ID', index: 'Emp_ID', width: 150, stype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true },
                   { name: 'Designation', index: 'Designation', width: 150, editable: true },
                   { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 150, editable: true },
                   { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 150, align: "right", editable: true },
                   { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 150, align: "right", editable: true },

        ],

        multiselect: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        jsonReader: {
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            //records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
            root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        caption: 'Employee details'
    }).navGrid('#pager', { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" });
    jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", {}, {}, {}, {},
 {
       multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeAfterReset: true,
  onClose: function () {
   //do work
   return true; // return true to close the search grid
 }
  });
  })
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table style="">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; background-color: skyblue; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt; color: chocolate;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: central; padding: 50px;">


                <table id="dataGrid" style="text-align: center;">          </table>
                <div id="pager"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: "jqGrid is not working" - can you elaborate ?  Is anything displayed on the screen ?  If you run it in Chrome with F12 Developer Options open, are any errors reported in the Console tab ?  My best bet is that it's missing one of the .js files  (and the Network tab will confirm this)

Comment: No errors when I press f12. I will tell you main point, when I create empty sample project after run my application the page extension is showing with .aspx. when I create 'Asp.net Web Form Site' then extension is not showing. I am using url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default5.aspx/GetDataFromDB") %>' into jquery na so may be this only the problem. The above my old code working correct into empty project after adding some pages and its not working when create new project. @Mike Gledhill

Comment: Actually, what the heck is that "Default5.aspx" file, which you're attempting to load data from ?   Do you have a "Default5.aspx.cs" which contains C# code which returns some data, and if so, can you post this code ?   If this page is meant to be returning JSON data, then your first step should be to open this URL directly in a browser and verify that that .aspx file is working as expected.

Comment: Table is showing, paging, searching every thing desing is coming but data is not displaying. @Mike Gledhill

Comment: Yes its contain C# sharp code and working perfectly into visual studio 2010. And also working into Visual Studio 2013 empty project. Its not Woking with new project. @Mike Gledhill

Comment: Empty project site showing site with extension localhost:xyz/Default8.aspx and If I created new sample project after running site look like http://localhost:51077/Default8 . @Mike Gledhill

Comment: Again, forget about your webpage for a minute, if you open this "Default5.aspx" URL in your browser, what gets displayed ?  Raw JSON data ?  JSON data embedded in an HTML page ?  Nothing ?  An error ?

Comment: I have created two project one is empty project later added some page into visual studio 2013 after running site like Default8.aspx and working perfectly. I have created another project that is not empty project. I selected 'Asp.net Web Form Site'  after adding code then going for run site look like Default8. There is no extension for this site. I am new in json dont know shoing into html or not. @Mike Gledhill

Comment: You MUST be able to test the URL which is supposed to return your JSON data (without any HTML markup) in a browser.  If you aren't able to do this, it's not surprising that your jqGrid control can't do it...  Here's an example of how a working .aspx page would return some valid JSON data: http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.htm

Comment: This is my local host url:  http://localhost:51077/Default5 and this is not contain contain any .aspx extension after running site. @Mike Gledhill